# Multi-stage build for R application

Tags: r, linux, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to create a multi-stage build for an R application based on `rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04` image.

The reason that I'm based on that image is to install binary packages via `apt-get` as suggested in order to improve building time.

If I build the image without multi-stage build, the final image size is `2.32GB`, so i need to decrease the final size with multi-stage build.

The approach that I follow is create an `alpine:latest` image and copy the `app` folder from builder, and the R libraries installed `(/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/`) and the binaries packages located in `/usr/share/doc`.

The final image doesn't work, because no commands to execute the app is installed.

The Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04 as builder


# # system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    pandoc \
    ...
    libxml2-dev 

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -qq \
    r-cran-config \
    ...
    r-cran-tidyverse 

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('other-packages'), dependencies=T)"    


# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir -p /root/bloomapp/tmp
COPY . /root/bloomapp
COPY .Renviron Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/


FROM alpine:latest

#Copy app to alpine
COPY --from=builder /root/bloomapp /root/bloomapp
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/doc /usr/share/doc

WORKDIR /root/bloomapp/

EXPOSE 3838
```

Is reasonable this approach? or exist any other better way to do multi-stage build for a R app image?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you need a multi-stage build to decrease the file size? One simple trick would be to delete the package repository cache after package installation with `apt` (and to do it in the same `RUN` command, to avoid creating large intermediate layers — see [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get)). (That being said, a multi-stage build is in principle not a bad idea.)

Comment: Adding ```rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*``` at the end of ```RUN``` commands, the image size decrease from ```2.32GB``` to ```2.28GB```, helps, but is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to starting with a rocker build, use a slim image & install R from source in the `builder` stage of the multistage build.

See R Installation docs here for reference: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-R-under-Unix_002dalikes

> - Choose a directory to install the **R tree** (R is not just a binary, but has additional data sets, help files, font metrics etc). Let us call this place `R_HOME`. Untar the source code. This should create directories src, doc, and several more under a top-level directory... If the configure and make commands execute successfully, a shell-script front-end called R will be created and copied to `R_HOME/bin`.